# Django rest framework csrf exempt when doing ajax post call

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to pass data via `ajax POST` request but getting a `403 ERROR`.

I've tried to use `CsrfExemptMixin` from `braces.views` but that doesn't resolve the issue.

I'm new to api calls with `drf` so maybe my methods are incorrect.

**View**

```
class DialogListView(CsrfExemptMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # queryset = Dialog.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DialogSerializer

    # http_method_names = ['get', 'delete']


    def get_queryset(self):
        data = self.request.data
        print('helllo')
        print(self.request.data)
        # for k in data:
        #     print(k)
        try:
            owner_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=User.objects.get(username=data.get('owner')))
            opponent_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=User.objects.get(username=data.get('opponent')))
            return Dialog.objects.get(Q(owner=owner_profile,
                                        opponent=opponent_profile) |
                                      Q(owner=opponent_profile,
                                        opponent=owner_profile))

        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            owner_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=User.objects.get(username=data.get('owner')))
            opponent_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=User.objects.get(username=data.get('opponent')))
            return Dialog.objects.create(owner=owner_profile,
                                         opponent=opponent_profile)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, figured it out. I've added `csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'`, into `data` key with other data that has been passed via `POST` request.
`